# autosys job automation for dat files

Tags: autosys, dat-protocol

We have processed data and we wil get dat files for every 4 days so when ever those dat files created we need to run autosys job, is there any script that will work for my Linux box?

Need support on this . So far manual particular time given in autosys to run those files. But we need auto run when ever dat files created every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an Autosys in-built file watcher job and trigger your job when the file watcher gets succeeded.

Here is how that look like:

If the job name is "joba" and it needs to complete upon arrival of a file name `test.dat` in the directory `/tmp/autosys/`, here is the JIL

```
insert_job: joba
job_type: FW
machine: linuxbox
watch_file: /tmp/autosys/test.dat
watch_interval: 60 (will probe the path every 60 seconds)
watch_min_file_size: 1024 (minimum file size to confirm if we have a good file represented in bytes, optional attribute)
permission : xxxx
```

Comment: I think this answer will benefit from more details on how to "create an Autosys in-built file watcher job"